# Operator Overloading with Templates inside of a BST

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I currently have a binary search tree setup, utilizing templates to allow me to easily change the type of data within the binary search tree. At the moment, I'm having trouble overloading the studentRecord class which contains the data to be stored in the tree. I need to overload the comparison operators within this class, so that my BST can properly compare two objects based on one of their contents (in this case, the student ID). However, despite overloading the operators within studentRecord, proper comparisons are still not occurring.

**Details below:**

At the moment, the bst object studentTree has been created, of type

```
bst<studentRecord *> studentTree;
```

studentRecord is the following class:

```
// studentRecord class
class studentRecord{
public:
    // standard constructors and destructors
    studentRecord(int studentID, string lastName, string firstName, string academicYear){ // constructor
        this->studentID=studentID;
        this->lastName=lastName;
        this->firstName=firstName;
        this->academicYear=academicYear;
    }

    friend bool operator > (studentRecord &record1, studentRecord &record2){
        if (record1.studentID > record2.studentID)
            cout << "Greater!" << endl;
        else
            cout << "Less then!" << endl;
        return (record1.studentID > record2.studentID);
    }

private:
    // student information
    string studentID;
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
    string academicYear;
};
```

Whenever new items are added to my BST, they must be compared with each other. Hence, I wanted to overload the studentRecord class, so that when this comparison process occurs, the studentIDs are compared (as otherwise, an invalid comparison will be made).

However, my insertion function never uses my overloaded comparison functions. Instead, it seems to be comparing the two objects some other way, resulting in invalid sorting within the BST. Part of my insert function is below -- it is important to note that both toInsert and nodePtr->data should be of type studentRecord, due to the templating process occuring.

```
// insert (private recursive function)
template<typename bstType>
void bst<bstType>::insert(bstType & toInsert, bstNodePtr & nodePtr){
    // check to see if the nodePtr is null, if it is, we've found our insertion point (base case)
    if (nodePtr == NULL){
        nodePtr = new bst<bstType>::bstNode(toInsert);
    }

    // else, we are going to need to keep searching (recursive case)
    // we perform this operation recursively, to allow for rotations (if AVL tree support is enabled)
    // check for left
    else if (toInsert < (nodePtr->data)){ // go to the left (item is smaller)
        // perform recursive insert
        insert(toInsert,nodePtr->left);

        // AVL tree sorting
        if(getNodeHeight(nodePtr->left) - getNodeHeight(nodePtr->right) == 2 && AVLEnabled)
            if (toInsert < nodePtr->left->data)
                rotateWithLeftChild(nodePtr);
            else
                doubleRotateWithLeftChild(nodePtr);
    }
```

Also, here is a portion of the BST class defintion

```
// BST class w/ templates
template <typename bstType>
class bst{

private: // private data members

    // BST node structure (inline class)
    class bstNode{
    public: // public components in bstNode

        // data members
        bstType data;
        bstNode* left;
        bstNode* right;

        // balancing information
        int height;

        // constructor
        bstNode(bstType item){
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
            data = item;
            height = 0;
        }

        // destructor
        // no special destructor is required for bstNode     
    };

    // BST node pointer
    typedef bstNode* bstNodePtr;

public: // public functions.....
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this? Am I overloading the wrong class or the wrong function? Any help is appreciated -- I seem to be getting lost since so many different things are occurring at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tree is a tree of *pointers*. So when you try to insert an element into the tree the values of the *pointers* is compared. So your overloaded operator is not called. If you want to use the overloaded operator then you should create `bst<studentrecord>`

Comment: My apologizes for my previous comment -- your answer was correct. I simply misunderstood your response initially.

Answer (score 2):

You instantiate your template class like this:

```
bst<studentRecord *> studentTree;
```

So **bstType == studentRecord***

The insert looks like this then:

```
template<studentRecord*>
void bst<studentRecord*>::insert(studentRecord*& toInsert, bst<studentRecord*>::bstNodePtr & nodePtr);
```

so you are doing a pointer comparison and this is why your operator is not called as Asha allready pointed out.

More so you overload only the greater than operator (>) but in insert you use the less than operator (<). If you would really compare two objects of type studentRecord in insert the code should't even compile and should complain that it is unable to find an appropriate less than operator.

More so I can point out several problems in your code:

1. studentRecord.studentID is of type string? However you try to assign it an integer in the constructor. This will simply convert the integer to char and assign the character to the string - so quite probably not what you intended.
2. You are missing the less than operator.

Below you code and some thest code that demonstrates the operator gets called when comparing two instances of type studentRecord. You can also see what would be the effects of the missing less than operator by commenting the operator definition in the studentRecord class (-> compile error).

```
class studentRecord
{
public:

    studentRecord(int studentID) : studentID(studentID)
    { 
    }

    bool operator > (studentRecord &record)
    {
        return (studentID > record.studentID);
    }

    /* Uncomment to get rid of the compile error!
    bool operator < (studentRecord &record)
    {
        return studentID < record.studentID;
    }
    */

private:
    // student information
    int studentID;
};

int main()
{
    studentRecord r1(10);
    studentRecord r2(5);

    if ( r1 < r2 )
    {
        cout << "It works! " << "r1 less than r2" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It works! " << "r1 greater than r2" << endl;
    }

    if ( r1 > r2 )
    {
        cout << "It works! " << "r1 greater than r2" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "It works! " << "r1 less than r2" << endl;
    }
}
```

As an ending comment probably it would be a good idea to provide the other comparison operators too ( >=, <=, == and !=.

Comment: To be honest, I actually did have additional overload operators in my original code. However, I simply did not include them in my post to reduce the amount of content someone would need to read to help me solve my problem.